# How to setup shared github action workflow with secrets and node modules

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a main job like the below and two other parallel jobs are dependent on the first job including secret generation and node module installation like secret setup and install node module.

[image]

I tried to make it work with `needs` but all the environment setup is gone with `needs`.
And reusable workflow seems to just setup keys.

```
name: build
on: [push]
jobs:
   codepull:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:

         - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
           with:
           node-version: '16.16.0'
         
         - name: install node module
           run |
             yarn

          - name: secrets
           run |
             yarn secrets

       codepull-ios:
           - name: build ios
             run |
                ...

    codepull-ios:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
           ...

    codepull-android:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
           ...
```

I checked reusable workflow but those seems only for setting up env variables.

Anyone tried to do similar things?

Comment: Please share what you get and what you expected. It is not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps also create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

jobs runs in it's own environment so do not share nothing by default.
By you can define jobs output and use it in the dependant job, like:

```
name: build
on: [push]
jobs:
   codepull:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      outputs: # define here the job output
        one-secret: ${{ steps.secret.outputs.my-secret }}
      steps:

         - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
           with:
           node-version: '16.16.0'
         
         - name: install node module
           run |
             yarn

          - name: secrets
            id: secret
           run |
             yarn secrets

             secretkey=$(cat password.txt) # stupid example to take some var from somewhere
             echo "::set-output name=my-secret::$secretkey"


       codepull-ios:
           - name: build ios
             run |
                ...

    codepull-ios:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       needs: 
         - codepull
       steps:
         -run:
           echo needs.codepull.outputs.one-secret # use the secrets
           ...

    codepull-android:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
           ...
```

Some link to the doc [about jobs output](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs)